# When do Taylor series converge quickly?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, power-series, taylor-expansion

The function $e^x$ has a Maclaurin series $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

It also has various Taylor series expansions centered at $x$-values other than zero, for example $x=3$: $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^3}{n!} (x-3)^n.$$

If we approximate $e^{1/2}$ using the first series above, our approximation converges to the exact value very quickly (|error| < 0.001 after 4 terms). If we use the second series, it converges more slowly (|error| < 0.001 after 13 terms).

I suspect this happens because $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is closer to zero than it is to 3. Do Taylor series always converge more quickly near the center of convergence? If not, is there a general result that tells us when this happens?

Comment: To approximate $e^{\frac{1}{2}}$ using $e^3$ looks just weird

Comment: Yeah, maybe not the most practical example. I'm more interested in the general principle.

Comment: The Taylor series have a bound http://math.jasonbhill.com/courses/fall-2010-math-2300-005/lectures/taylor-polynomial-error-bounds which, as you can see, converges more quickly when you are close to the center (strictly less than 1).

Comment: The error in the approximation is given by the tail of the series. If you pick the centre of your Taylor series to be close to the point you're approximating, then $(x-a)$ is small, and $(x-a)^{n}$ will be even smaller. This can give you effective bounds on the error.

Comment: Lagrange remainder and alternating series remainder.  Use those and it should be clear.

Comment: Not a rigorous argument, but for a function like $e^x$, the Taylor polynomial will take longer to approximate points farther from the center as it will take more terms for it to 'wrap' around the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taylor series is:
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f^{'}(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2!}f^{''}(x_0)+....+\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0)+R_n$$

where $R_n$ is Lagrange remainder,

$$R_n=\frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}f^{(n)}(x^*)$$

( here $x^*$ is value between $x_0$ and $x$ )

So, the rate of convergence is depending upon $(x-x_0)$ **with respect to** $x$,
hence this difference will decide the convergence.

**For example**,

To calculate $e^\frac{1}{2}$, series: $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$ is better and

To caculate $e^\frac{5}{2}$, series: $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^3}{n!} (x-3)^n.$ is better

(See differences between $x_0$ and $x$ to understand the above statement)

Refer: [Taylor Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html)